# How to convert a color pdf or images to black & white or grayscale pdf using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, winforms, itext, pdf-generation

When I am trying to convert colored pdf or images to black & white or grayscale pdf [iTextSharp](http://habjan.blogspot.com/2013/09/proof-of-concept-converting-pdf-files.html) in C# WinForm application, it's not working, it also has issues with transparent images. While conversion it turns background in black for transparent images. I am using following code to convert to pdf first

```
string urlpdf = output.Replace(".png", ".pdf").Replace(".jpeg", ".pdf").Replace(".jpg", ".pdf").Replace(".PNG", ".pdf").Replace(".JPEG", ".pdf").Replace(".JPG", ".pdf");
                    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(urlpdf, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        PdfWriter PdfIns = PdfWriter.GetInstance(docPNG, fs);
                        docPNG.Open();
                        iTextSharp.text.Image pdfImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        if (comboBox8.SelectedIndex == 1)
                        {
                            pdfImage.ScaleToFit(rec);                               
                            pdfImage.SetAbsolutePosition((docPNG.PageSize.Width - pdfImage.ScaledWidth) / 2, (docPNG.PageSize.Height - pdfImage.ScaledHeight) / 2);                              
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pdfImage.ScalePercent((float)numericUpDown4.Value);
                        }                       

                        docPNG.Add(pdfImage);
                        docPNG.CloseDocument();
                        docPNG.Close();
                    }
```

and then to grayscale or black & white as follows-

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.converter.PdfContentToGrayscaleConverter grayscaleConverter = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.converter.PdfContentToGrayscaleConverter();

            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFile))
            {
                using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fsOutput);

                    document.Open();
                    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

                    int numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;

                    try
                    {
                        for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= numberOfPages; pageNumber++)
                        {
                            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSizeWithRotation = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageNumber);

                            document.SetPageSize(pageSizeWithRotation);
                            document.NewPage();

                            int SecondChance = 0;
                        conti:  ///continue again
                            try
                            {
                                // >>> CONVERT CURRENT PAGE TO GRAYSCALE
                                grayscaleConverter.Convert(reader, pageNumber);
                                // <<<<
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                if (SecondChance == 0)
                                {
                                    SecondChance++;
                                    goto conti;   ///junmp to conti
                                }
                            }

                            PdfImportedPage pip = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);

                            if (pageSizeWithRotation.Rotation == 90 || pageSizeWithRotation.Rotation == 270)
                            {
                                cb.AddTemplate(pip, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, pageSizeWithRotation.Height);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cb.AddTemplate(pip, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); }

                    cb.PdfDocument.Close();
                    document.Close(); document.Dispose(); document = null;
                    writer.Close(); writer.Dispose(); writer = null;
                    reader.Close(); reader.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you looking for a solution for `C#` and `vb.net`? If not you should probably just use one of the tags.

Comment: Come now, Matt, in this modern age you really can't read both? :)

Comment: @MattBeldon, i am mainly looking solution for C#, but if someone knows in vb.net i would try to use that in c#.

Comment: What exactly is a Black&White / Grayscale PDF for you? In particular: Does merely the final result need to use only black&white or grayscale colors? Or are other color types also forbidden as intermediary colors? And do those blacks, whites, and grays need to be from a specific color space?

Comment: @mkl, As we mostly have two types of printing color and black&white, so basically all colored images present in pdf or docs should be converted to black&white.

Comment: So the actual embedded images need to be b&w, it doesn't suffice to try and use PDF methods to have them displayed b&w?

Comment: @mkl, i am using iTextSharp to do that, but not working properly

Comment: Please share a sample pdf. Furthermore, please share that `PdfContentToGrayscaleConverter`; it is not part of itext itself.